# How to configure ElasticBeanstalk container command into .ebextensions

Tags: reactjs, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, next.js, ebextensions

I have deployed my react SSR app to ElasticBeanstalk, before running npm start there should be command to run "npm run-script build" to make a build, but unfortunately npm start is running and app crashes due to no code build found on server, I setup .ebextension to run container command.

.ebextensions
    container-command.config

here my code is

```
commands:
deploy:
  command: "npm run-script build"
  leader_only: true
```

command is not running on server I am facing error

Error: Could not find a valid build in the '/var/app/current/.next' directory! Try building your app with 'next build' before starting the server.
at Server.readBuildId (/var/app/current/node_modules/next-server/dist/server/next-server.js:435:23)
at new Server (/var/app/current/node_modules/next-server/dist/server/next-server.js:44:29)
at module.exports (/var/app/current/node_modules/next-server/index.js:4:10)
at module.exports (/var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js:2:161)
at start (/var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js:1:323)
at nextStart (/var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-start.js:22:125)
at /var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next:29:346

Comment: You should build your app outside of your production environment. Then deploy it already built to elastic beanstalk.

Comment: well this is not good practice at all, when we deploy app it should run build command to install code on server otherwise we need to upload node_modules as well.

Comment: Yes. This is why https://hub.docker.com/_/amazonlinux exists.